# Is there a way to set $DISPLAY inside a virtualenv to my standard display?

Tags: python, matplotlib, virtualenv

When I try to plot with `matplotlib`, I get an `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display`, because I'm executing my python script from within a virtualenv in a vm on a mac :) In IPython I can do %matplotlib inline. Is there a way to tell the venv to use my standard display?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're mixing things:

- Jupyter (previously know as python) can tell that the object has an representation (whether it's a string, a float, an image, a js script...) after calling `plt.plot()`. This representation is embedded into a html page, which *can* be displayed in a browser. Do mind that all this happens without using `DISPLAY`
- In that virtual machine, are you using a graphical interface ("desktop") or bare-bones terminal? if the previous, `DISPLAY` should be set. If the later, then you cannot display on bare-bones terminal, and should use other resources to forward display or output your image as a file.